# Object literal may only specify known > properties, and 'waitFor' does not exist in type - Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

The below code errors in the **return** where: `waitFor: 'validation'`

The Typescript error I get is:

> Type '{ waitFor: string; validation: { target: { locators: { type:
> string; value: string; }[]; }; type: string; failIfFound: boolean;
> match: string; }; timeoutInMilliseconds: number; }' is not assignable
> to type 'WaitReturn[]'.   Object literal may only specify known
> properties, and 'waitFor' does not exist in type
> 'WaitReturn[]'.ts(2322)

I think that maybe I'm returning an object when it's expecting an array but I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
  import { Validation } from '../../contracts/validation.types';

type WaitParams = {
  element: string;
  exists: boolean;
  timeoutInMilliseconds: number;
};

type WaitReturn = {
  waitFor: string;
  validation: Validation;
  timeoutInMilliseconds: number;
};

module.exports = function wait({ element, exists = true, timeoutInMilliseconds = 30000 }: WaitParams): WaitReturn[] {
  if (!element) {
    throw new Error('Missing required attribute element');
  }
  return {
    waitFor: 'validation',
    validation: {
      target: {
        locators: [
          {
            type: 'css',
            value: element,
          },
        ],
      },
      type: 'element_match',
      failIfFound: !exists,
      match: '',
    },
    timeoutInMilliseconds,
  };
};
```

Comment: "I think that maybe I'm returning an object when it's expecting an array but I'm not sure how to fix this."  Yes, that's what the error says.  You've annotated the return type of `wait()` as `WaitReturn[]`, an array of `WaitReturn` elements.  Is that not what you want to do?  What are you *trying* to do?  If you want to return an array then wrap the return value in an array literal like [this](https://tsplay.dev/we0RgW); if you want to return a single object then change the return type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGkKoW); if you want something else then please explain.

Comment: omg i'm so silly, yes! so the error with this was that instead of WaitReturn[], it should be WaitReturn

Comment: So is this a typo? Like, did you *accidentally* write `WaitReturn[]` when you mean to write `WaitReturn`?  Or is something else going on?  I'm trying to figure out if this is a question that needs an answer or one that can be closed as caused by a typo and unlikely to help others.